# How can I automatically number rows in Excel based off two different criteria, one being date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to automatically number rows in Excel based on "grouping" first by 'category', then by 'date'. I have manually applied numbers in the image to illustrate what I am looking for. 
[image: Excel Example]!

I have exhausted all vanilla Excel options I know if; ideally this can be achieved without any macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` with a dynamic range:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)
```

Here I'm using a range that increases in size as the formula is copied down, notice the row number is locked with `$`.

[image]

Comment: Wow,, thank you so much, not sure how I couldn't grasp that before. I had one more criteria but now I see you can add as many as desired. Thanks again.